# Yahoo Pipes to loop through all pages

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I am looking to pull job postings from a site that has multiple pages of postings. I can pull the content from one page

On a simple example I can get it to iterate and grab page content (this is a simple example site base)

However when I take the first example and try to clean the data (I can't use the Xpath filter to grab the HTML id and I cand seem to find a way to limit the scope elsewhere. Here is what I am trying (regex, rename...):
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=3619ea93d66e47442659a1976746ba6c

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your link requires a Yahoo login, would suggest you copy the relevant stuff into your question.